# Implementing jsGrid with Angular 4 "Error: JsGridModule is not an NgModule"

Tags: angular, jsgrid

Trying to implement jsgrid with angular 4 and followed all the steps mentioned on the git https://github.com/jinhduong/ng2-jsgrid. But getting Error: JsGridModule is not an NgModule.

Need help.

Thank you
Hrushikesh Patel

Comment: did you install all three dependencies `jquery`, `jsgrid` and `ng2-jsgrid`?

Comment: Yes i did and follow the all the steps mentioned.

Comment: then check your `angular-cli.json` -> `"scripts:[]"` are listed these js files in order

Comment: Do i really need to include those, as those are not mentioned?

Comment: yes npm install --save won't write to scripts because different libraries use different folder structure. you want to manually add it.

Comment: added all the 3 to the script as below still same issue.         "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid.min.js",
        "../node_modules/ng2-jsgrid/ng2-jsgrid.js"
      ],

Answer (score 0):

You can always check their git repo files. How they do it.

here is ths `angular-cli.json` [link](https://github.com/jinhduong/ng2-jsgrid/blob/master/.angular-cli.json)

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid.js"
  ]
```

and `app.module.ts` file [link](https://github.com/jinhduong/ng2-jsgrid/blob/master/demo/app/app.module.ts)

`import { JsGridModule } from '../../src/ng2-jsgrid';` //yours will be in different folder where you installed (node_modules)

and imports

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsGridModule
 ]
```

this should work. if not check the angular versions they have used [here](https://github.com/jinhduong/ng2-jsgrid/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: Did everything what they have said. but one thing i am seeing is the version of the angular. they are using 4.0.0 and in my case its 4.2.4. Will that effect?

Comment: good chance. please double check you are pointing to correct folder path `ng2-jsgrid`. if not you will see a red line under `import { JsGridModule }`

Comment: the path is good not getting any redline. checked everything.

Comment: then it might be version problem, open an issue in git hub

Comment: Already opened a issue in github.https://github.com/jinhduong/ng2-jsgrid/issues/2